# Will windows 10 p2p updates be able to deliver updates to hosts without internet access?

Tags: windows-10

The information needed to answer this might not be available publicly yet -- but when it becomes available (or if someone in the know can answer now ...) -- will windows 10 be able to deliver p2p updates to hosts which don't have internet access?  As in -- suppose you have a LAN which consists of two types of hosts:

1. a windows 10 host with internet access
2. several windows 10 hosts which are connected to the same LAN as group (1) and which have full network connectivity to the host in group 1 -- but which do not themselves have any access to the internet

Will this technology be able to deliver updates to the hosts in group (2) from the host in group (1)?

Assuming not -- then the followup question -- what if the hosts in group (2) have only very restricted access to the internet -- what's the minimal set of internet access needed by group (2) to allow distribution of updates from group (1) to group (2)?